# Avoiding infinite recursion with mfix

Tags: haskell, recursion

Let:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

test :: [a] -> Maybe Int
test []       = Just 0
test (_ : xs) = mdo
    unless (i == 0) Nothing -- 1
    i <- test xs            -- 2
    Just i
```

I'm looking for an explanation of why calling e.g. `test "hey"` results in an infinite loop, and in general how to avoid such behavior when dealing with `mfix`. Also, is there a way to correct the previous toy-example without exchanging the order of (1) and (2)?

Comment: You're nesting `mfix`-based recursion in standard Haskell recursion? _Interesting_. Could you give some elaboration what this is actually supposed to do, and why you want it?

Comment: You have to imagine a more sophisticated monad than `Maybe`, that instead of just noping out with `Nothing`, saves an error message and continues with the rest of the list (2). The point is that (1) needs some information that is available only at the end of the list, and I can't just swap (1) and (2) because I want the error messages to be saved in the correct order. I'm sorry if this looks convoluted, I don't know if there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Actually, it could be sufficient to swap (1) and (2) and reverse the list before `test`ing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Aside, I find that explicit `do`…`rec`… (formerly known as `DoRec`, now enabled by `RecursiveDo`) tends to be clearer than `mdo`, because `rec` makes it clearer which bindings are meant to be recursive, while `mdo` selects them implicitly (when it effectively desugars to `rec` blocks).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Ordinary and monadic recursion are nicely complementary. I’ve used them together for example in a typechecker, which recursively checks a term, and returns the term annotated with its type substituted in the *final* type environment, something like: `typecheck :: Term () -> Typecheck (Term Type); typecheck term = do { rec { (term', _type) <- check finalEnv term; finalEnv <- getEnv }; pure term' }; check :: TypeEnv -> Term () -> Typecheck (Term Type, Type)`

Comment: @JonPurdy That's exactly my use-case. In practice, it's even more complex than the toy-example I provided, as (1) and (2) are really mutually dependent. Anyways, I just can't seem to make it work with `mfix`.

Comment: @giofrida: Presumably you just had excessive strictness somewhere, but without more details of your actual code, I can’t really advise how to change it while still using monadic recursion. Also, while this pattern is very nice in simple typecheckers, I’ve mostly moved away from it in favour of giving AST nodes stable IDs; there are sundry approaches for that, but regardless, the upshot is that you can easily add & transform all kinds of different annotations without needing to rewrite the whole AST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of your code:

```hs
mdo unless (i == 0) Nothing
    i <- test xs
    Just i
```

desugars to:

```hs
mfix (\i -> do unless (i == 0) Nothing
               j <- test xs
               Just j)
```

After renaming the binding of `i` to `j` for clarity in the `do`-expression.

The first `mfix` law states that `mfix f = _|_ iff f is strict`. The `f` in this case is:

```hs
\i -> do unless (i == 0) Nothing
         j <- test xs
         Just j
```

And this function is strict. (If you call `f` with `_|_`, you'll get `_|_`.) Thus `mfix` on it is `_|_` by definition. Substituting back to your original, we get:

```hs
test []       = Just 0
test (_ : xs) = _|_
```

This says that unless you pass `test` the empty list, it'll always diverge no matter what other input you pass to it.

That's the theory side of it, of course. But practically, I don't see why you'd ever want to do this sort of recursion, mixing a recursively defined function with a monadic-value recursive subpart. Unless this is a mere curiosity, there's probably a better way to structure your program that avoids this issue. But for that, you'll have to share more information as to what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer; I wrote a comment about the context, below the question. But yeah, in the end I just refactored the code.